# Items of a UITabBar are not being highlighted when selected

Tags: ios5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm having a trouble with a UITabBar with UITabBarItem added programmatically, the selected item is not being highlighted in white as usual.

Here's the source

```
UIImage *imageX = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sample" image:imageX tag:1];    
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabBarItem, nil];
[tabBar setItems:array];
```

When I select the item, the method didSelectItem of the delegate is called and the action is executed, but the image is not being highlighted by the bar...

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
```

Anyone know what's wrong ? I have to call other method to pass the highlighted image or something like that ?

The items of the tab bar are added programmatically but the tab bar I add via Storyboard.

Also, I did a test where the tab bar and the tab bar items are added via Storyboard, and everything works, including the highlighted icon is shown when it's selected

Thanks !

Comment: I think it was a bug in iOS 6. In iOS 7 this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding code in `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;` function :

```
self.tabBar.selectedItem = item;
```

I don't know why I have to do this, but it's working.